# Angular open a dialog and return observable for action result

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I would like to show a dialog by code (not MatDialog but a custom one) and then return an Observable that will trigger a result to the caller.

Something like this:

```
    @ViewChild(PopupComponent)
      myDialog: PopupComponent;


public show(){
   this.myDialog.show().subscribe(v => {
       if(v.OkClicked){
          console.log('ok clicked!');
       }
   });
}


export interface DialogResult{
    OkClicked: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'f-popup',
  outputs: [ "onClose" ],
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})

private _result : ReplaySubject<DialogResult>;
private _obsResult: Observable<DialogResult>;

public show(): Observable<DialogResult>(){
    // show the dialog
    if(!this._result){
        this._result = new ReplaySubject<DialogResult>(1);
    }
    return this._obsResult.asObservable();
}

public onOkClick(){
   let result: DialogResult = {OkClicked: true};
   this._obsResult.next(result);
}

public onClosed(){
    this._obsResult.complete();
    this._obsResult = null;
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this._obsResult) {
      this._obsResult.complete();
      this._obsResult = null;
   }
}
```

The dialog is not destroyed when it is closed, it is a component inside anohther component that is shown and hidden.
My question is, is it a good way to recreate a Subject on every show of the dialog? Are there memory leaks for this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do it the other way around.

You can pass a `data` object with an observable to your dialog when you open it. When in the `PopupComponent` the action is confirmed (OK is clicked) you subscribe to the passed `action$` observable. You can optionally pass in a `cancel$` observable to do something when user clicks cancel or close.

```
interface PopupData<T> { 
  action$: Observable<T> // Action to which you subscribe on OK
  cancel$?: Observable<void> // Optional observable for handling cancel
}

@Component({
  selector: 'f-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})

public data: PopupData<any>;

public show(data: PopupData<T>): Observable<T>(){
  this.data = data;
}

public onOkClick(){
  this.data.action$.subscribe();
}

public onClosed(){
  if (this.data.cancel$) {
    this.data.cancel$.subscribe();
  }
}
```

---

### UPDATE:

*I will answer your question, since you are apparently not interested in suggestions for alternative solutions, but please take note of the comment at the bottom of the answer!*

You are not totally good when it comes to memory problems. When the component gets destroyed you still have a living `ReplaySubject` on your `_result` property. I would suggest you also complete and unsubscribe from your `ReplaySubject` in the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook. Another issue is that you subscribe to the observable in in your `show()` call but you do not unsubscribe. Since you use a Subject the observable is multicast meaning you create a memory leak there. You can consider using a pipe like `take(1)` or `first()` to make it unicast, that is probably the right thing to do, since you probably want to be notified only once per opened dialog.

You can also consider using a normal Subject, since there is no need for replay functionality here (at least with the code you shared I see no reason why).

Then there is this line:

```
return this._obsResult.asObservable();
```

Should probably be:

```
return this._result.asObservable();
```

I would suggest following changes:

Change to Subject

```
private _result: Subject<DialogResult>;
```

Add complete and unsubscribe for Subject to `ngOnDestroy`

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this._obsResult) {
    this._obsResult.complete();
    this._obsResult = null;
  }
  if (this._result) {
    this._result.complete();
    this._result.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And return unicast value instead of multicast using `take(1)` pipe:

```
return this._result.asObservable().pipe(take(1));
```

---

**A last comment:**

In my opinion you are over-engineering a simple dialog box. I would suggest to rethink and consider simplifying your popup logic.

Comment: The example I have made is realy simple. In the finished component the show method has a few other paramters like dialog options, eg. show close button, position and so on, because of this I would like to avoid passing a parameter.
The way works very well, the only problem is, that I don't know if this way get's a memory problem...

Comment: Thanks for your help and the advice. I understand your last comment, but at the end the above example is only a very simple abstraction of the real component. At the end it will result in a kind of complex popup control. To give an example look at the devextreme  [popup](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Popup/Overview/jQuery/Light/) control with additional extensions like sweet alert brings it..